# Debian : my service doesn't autostart

Tags: linux, debian

I'm using debian 7 x64, I want to add a service autostart at boot but it doesn't work.

The command : "update-rc.d  defaults" works good and return me : update-rc.d: using dependency based boot sequencing

My script working when I use the command : service  start/stop
But when I restart the computer, the service is down.

My script start by :

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          scriptname
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start daemon at boot time
# Description:       Enable service provided by daemon.
### END INIT INFO
```

I don't understand what is wrong ?

Edit :

I tried another way for my script, I looked at this example : http://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/tutoriel/comment_transformer_un_programme_en_service and it works great. Always don't understand why the other way didn't work. Whatever it's good for me now, thank you for helping.

Comment: Have you added the script to `/etc/init.d/` before running `update-rc.d defaults`, and has the script in `/etc/init.d/` the proper rights (including execution flag)? Do you see any hint in `/var/log/` (messages/dmesg/syslog)?

Comment: Yes it is in /etc/init.d. The file authorizations are 755. I can launch a "service script start" and it works perfectly. I see nothing in logs, but I have many files in .gz !

Comment: @user3224275 Did you manage to solve the problem? I am experiencing the same one. Manually service is started or restarted without any problems. But it is not started automatically after system reboot.

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons can be the fact, that during OS boot launch script can`t find Java in known places: env var `JAVA_HOME`, path `/usr/bin/java`, etc.

In my case, there was a message in `/var/log/boot.log`:  `Unable to find Java`. It came from this part of [launch.script](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-tools/spring-boot-loader-tools/src/main/resources/org/springframework/boot/loader/tools/launch.script):

```
# Find Java
if [[ -n "$JAVA_HOME" ]] && [[ -x "$JAVA_HOME/bin/java" ]]; then
    javaexe="$JAVA_HOME/bin/java"
elif type -p java > /dev/null 2>&1; then
    javaexe=$(type -p java)
elif [[ -x "/usr/bin/java" ]];  then
    javaexe="/usr/bin/java"
else
    echo "Unable to find Java"
exit 1
fi
```

To fix that you need to be sure, that Java is available in paths during OS boot. Or you can follow recommendations from [deployment docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html) and use `.conf` file with `JAVA_HOME` value in it.